# ios iPA unix executable size 5MB too big

Tags: ios, ipa

I opened iPA package contents. the executable size is 5MB.

How can I reduce this? This is just a piece of code, I don't see any reason it would exceed even 1MB.

My iPA total size: 10MB

image folder size: 5MB

class code folder: 5MB

library libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a size: 5MB

xcodeproject size: 8MB

Comment: "Just a piece of code"? What does that mean? How much code? What frameworks do you link to? Why should 5MB even be a problem? 5MB is peanuts by today's standards.

Comment: Is this even your code? Or just some random ipa.

Comment: by piece of code I mean they are just textfiles like .M and .H files

Comment: They are not just text files.  The compiler converts that text to machine code, then it copies (links) in any libraries you are using.

Comment: This question should NOT have been closed

Answer (score 3):

> This is just a piece of code, I don't see any reason it would exceed even 1MB.

Your executable size is 5MB because you're linking in a library that's 5MB in size. The portion of the final executable that's due to your own code is likely pretty small, but you have to consider the size of the library that you've included.

Unlike system frameworks, which are dynamically linked, third party libraries are statically linked. The whole thing is copied into your executable at link time, which means that each library you add will increase your executable size.

> How can I reduce this?

The Core Plot source code is available if you don't already have it, so you could try to pare it down to a more limited form that excludes the things you don't need. For example, if you're not using pie charts in your app, you might remove CPTPieChart.m/h. Core Plot has a lot of features (annotations, animation, etc.) that you might not need in your app, and removing those could help reduce your app's footprint.

If you go this route, you might want to do it by adding a new target to the Core Plot project that includes only the parts you need -- that will make it easier to incorporate updates to Core Plot as they come along.